# Unable to open publications - an item with the title "Segments" already exists

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are experiencing a weird problem that we are not able to open publications. We do receive an error in GUI saying that "An item with the title "Segments" already exists in this location.". Has anyone experienced this before? No config/patches applied recently.

Environment:
SDL Tridion 2011 GA + HR # 1
IIS 7.5
.net 4
SQL Server 2008 R2

The error is happening even if we just try to view the publication properties or try to expand the publication from the GUI.

Below is the stack trace:

> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.FolderDal.Save(Folder folder, Boolean useTransaction)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.PublicationDal.CreateSegmentsRootFolder(Publication publication)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.PublicationDal.SolvePublicationWithoutSegmentRoot(Publication publication)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.PublicationDal.Read(Publication publication)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Publication.Load()
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Publication..ctor(UserContext userContext, TcmUri id)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.AddOeRootNode(XmlTextReader reader, TcmUri publicationUri)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.PostProcessListPublication(XmlTextReader reader, TcmUri publicationUri, PipelineContext context)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.ProcessListResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
>
> at Tridion.AudienceManagement.UI.DataExtenders.TreeExtender.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
>
> at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.<>c_*DisplayClass4.<ProcessResponse>b*_3(DataExtender extender)
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
>
> at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader reader, PipelineContext context)
>
> at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.Pipeline.ProcessResponse(XmlTextReader input, Object[] methodParameterValues)
>
> at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Lists.GetList(String id, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
>
> at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )

Any pointers/help will be appreciated?

**Quick Update and the Solution:**

We have opened Tridion CS ticket and able to resolve the issue with the help of Tridion CS. In our case, This is happening when we apply the security permissions for the publications. We still need to ensure the Root Cause of this issue on why it is happening. Table "FOLDERS_OWNING_PUBLICATIONS" of tridion_cm_email is not populated with the publication ids appropriately, when we applied the permissions and updating the table with publication ids resolved the issue.

NOTE: Before you try out the above solution, backup your DB and open a Tridion CS ticket for a solution. Also, provide you tridion_cm and tridion_cm_email db to customer support for anlaysis.

**Apply the Hotfix (OE_2011.1.1.82675) MSSQL or ORACLE depending on your DB :** https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/Outbound_Email_2011_SP1/index.aspx

Comment: Can you specify which version of SDL Tridion you are using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will likely need to contact SDL Tridion support to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Looking on stack trace, the issue happens in the Audience Management extension for the GUI. You certainly should contact SDL Tridion support to resolve this issue, but you can temporary turn off the Audience Management extension to proceed you work without it.
To do that you need to comment Audience Management related sections in the `/Configuration/editors` and `/Configuration/models` nodes in the `System.config` file.