# Issue Occured on content porter

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I am getting an error while doing content porter from DEV to QA. **An item with the title "Segments" already exists in this location**. Give some suggestion to resolve. It is occuring in those publication where audience manager is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a known bug in Audience Manager, which unfortunately has been impossible to reproduce so far and so doesn't have a fix yet. There is a workaround (requiring manual changes to the database) so you should contact Customer Support about it.

Audience Manager keeps track of changes to your BluePrint structure which require it to share Segments to different Publications. On rare occasions, something apparently goes wrong in this logic and it tries to create a "Segments" folder where one already exists - giving you this error message.

Any information you can give that might help us reproduce the problem would be very much appreciated; it's an elusive defect...

Comment: More detail:- 1.Earlier there was no audience manager tab in 000 empty parent and it was not enabled. But on content porter it started coming in empty parent,when we try to disable it by selection and deselection of address book to it but it is not removing audience manager settings in any way. we think it is also a bug in CMS 2011 GA 2. Now as other publications are inheriting 000 Empty parent it started showing the above error.  3. This error don't occur always.And currently we are resolving problem by restoring Sub_mgmt and email DB after content porter deployment whenever this error comes.

Comment: The top of your BluePrint is indeed supposed to get the Segments folder, if any of the child Publications have Audience Manager enabled. This is how the sharing works. But you are, of course, not supposed to get an error in the child Publications (which is the part that goes wrong somehow)

Answer (score 5):

Your issue most likely not be related to content porter. We have experienced recently similar issue and able to resolve with the help of Tridion Customer Support.

Are you able to browse the publication from Tridion GUI? In our case, when we browse the publication we have received the similar error message.

Please take a look at [Unable to open publications - an item with the title "Segments" already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402198/unable-to-open-publications-an-item-with-the-title-segments-already-exists)

Answer (score 0):

This probably means what it says: There is another item with the same name in that folder/structuregroup. Open up the GUI and check if there is an item with that exact name at that location. Check the complete Blueprint hierarchy!

Options to resolve this:

- Check your ContentPorter import settings (related content)
- Rename/(re)move the conflicting item

I don't think audience manager has anything to do with this error